# How to define non mandatory record that has composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have 3 models: Order, Organisation and OrderOrganisation.

Order will always exist, as will Organisation, but OrderOrganisation's existence is not mandatory.

One order can relate to many organisations, and this is the record that will header that information.

I can't change the database structure.

Here are my models.

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderOrganisation> OrderOrganisations { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderOrganisation> OrderOrganisations { get; set; }
}

public class OrderOrganisation
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderId")] //this is not right, i get an inner join not an outer join
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganisationId")] //this is not right, i get an inner join not an outer join
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

I know I need to add something to the context but I can't work out what?

Thanks

Comment: Change the type of `OrderId` and `OrganisationId` to `int?`

Comment: But they aren't optional? If you add an OrderOrganisation record, you must supply both.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what doesn't work. You can't have an `OrderOrganisation` without both an Order and an Organaisation so it seems correct that it does an inner join.

Comment: That would be true if OrderOrganisation was the main table of the query. When Order is the main table and no OrderOrganisations exist, no records are returned!

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderOrganisation> OrderOrganisations { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderOrganisation> OrderOrganisations { get; set; }
}

public class OrderOrganisation
{
    [ForeignKey("Order"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int? OrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Organisation"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? OrganisationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OrganisationId")]
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. Firstly, it needs a key on the table (which I added) but it doesn't work... it is still doing an inner join. Also, this makes the model incorrect as the properties are not nullable.